# Freemarker: Dynamically generate content based on object fields

Tags: java, freemarker

I am new to Freemarker. I want to dynamically generate the content in FTL, so that it will display all the fields in the object. In Java we can achive this through reflection. Not sure in Free marker.

Example:

```
class Employee{
String name;
String age;

//setter and getter methods
}

class Organization{
String orgName;
String location;

//setter and getter methods.
}
```

I want to write common ftl file which will display all the objects fields irrespective of data types.

I do not want to write in as below. I want it to be generic.

```
<td><div>${employee.name!}</div></td>
<td><div>${employee.age!}</div></td>
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You could use BeanUtils to map object properties to a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`employee?keys` should give you the JavaBeans property names, if you set up FM to not expose the methods too... Or if it does, you can use `employee[propertyName]?is_method` to filter them out. You can use `employee[propertyName]` to read the property value.

However, I'm pessimistic about doing these things so automatically in general. There will be always some properties that are too technical to print (like there's `class` just for starters), that has some funny type that FreeMarker won't convert to string properly or at all... If this kind of functionality is truly important in your project, you may want to mark those properties with annotations and then write `TemplatMethodModelEx` that gives you the names (and the other attributes needed for proper formatting etc.), or maybe a custom `ObjectWrapper` for the same purpose.